# How to store manual generated edit text value using array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6ajY.png)I have done dynamic generated EditText using RecyclerView and arranging the data using TextWatcher in RecyclerView, All the codes works fine but i facing a problem to store each integer value of EditText in an array. Let say I have 3 EditText in RecyclerView and I am putting each EditText a random number say 1,2 and 3, then i want to store each value in an array as [1,2,3].. Please let me know the solution and check my code below that how i can do this.

Thanks in Advance.

```
 holder.edtValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            ////////sum of edit text count//////////////

            if (s.length() > 0) {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                ans -= number;

            }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 0)

            {
                android.get(position).setTicketId(String.valueOf(0));
                holder.edtValue.setText("0");
            } else {
                try {
                    double e1 = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                    double e2 = Double.parseDouble(android.get(position).getAmount());
                    double e3 = Double.parseDouble(holder.text.getText().toString());

                    int j = (int) e1;// this is important edit text value to count and save in array...
                    int j1 = (int) e2;
                    int j2 = (int) e3;

                    asasaqty = new String[android.size()];

                    if (s.length() != 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < android.size(); i++) {

                            asasaqty[i] = android.get(i).getAmount();

                        }

                        System.out.println("==========asasaqty========" + Arrays.toString(asasaqty));

                    }

                    holder.txtAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(j * j1));
                    //android.add(position,).setTicketId(String.valueOf(e1*e2));
                    double e4 = j + j2;
                    android.get(position).setTicketId(String.valueOf(e4 * e2));
                    TicketBookFragment ticketBookFragment = new TicketBookFragment();
                    int value = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < android.size(); i++) {
                        value += Double.parseDouble(android.get(i).getTicketId());
                    }

                    ticketBookFragment.getamount(String.valueOf(value));


                    ////////sum of edit text count//////////////
                    // int number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                    //ans += number;
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////

                    for (int i = 0; i < holder.edtValue.length(); i++) {

                        int number = Integer.parseInt(holder.edtValue.toString());
                        ans += number;

                        allVALUE.add(String.valueOf(ans));

                        abcdd = allVALUE.toString();

                       //allVALUE.add(",");
                    }

                    //abcdd = s.toString();
                    //txtOutput.setText("sum is " + ans);
                    //int count = holder.edtValue.getText().toString().length();

                    //holder.edtValue.getText().toString()
                    //ticketBookFragment.getamount(String.valueOf(value),ans);
                    //ticketBookFragment.getamount(String.valueOf(value),count);


                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
```

Comment: The code is cut mid-way by the formatter, fix it if you can

Comment: the removed code is just commented code..ignore them

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the question. You want to input 1,2,3 into the EditText, and have an array [1,2,3].

If so, you have to be very precise about your input. Then use `String.split()` with the "," as the separator. This will give you an array of String. Then iterate over the array and create an array of ints with parseInt.

Another way is the iterate over the string and find every number.

One last way is to use Regex, and get all the numbers inside the string. Probably a very advanced solution but should mention it.

Comment: No sir, I have dyanmically generated edittext it can be 1 or 2 or 3 or so on , I have already mentioned. and i just want to store randomly generated edittext value in array.. please provide a proper solution.

Comment: If you already randomly generated the values. Why re-store them again? I don't really see what you're trying to do. You want to store the random values that you generated?

Comment: Sir, Actually the edittext is generated randomly as the data comes from backend api. If user input some value in each edittext then, i have to store each value of edittext in array. That's why i am storing it in array

Comment: Sir i just added a link of image in the description.. please see for more clarification

Comment: here is the link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6ajY.png. In the left hand side edittext , if user put any number in edittext then i have to store edittext value in array.